# Automatically adjust height of `\tikzpicture` to match height of `minipage` environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, scaling

Is there a way to scale the `tikzpicture` so that the two `minipage` 
environments have the same height?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c]{.50\textwidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
  \end{minipage}}\hfill%
 \fbox{\begin{minipage}[c]{.38\textwidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 

\centering  \begin{tikzpicture}{height=3cm}
 \draw (0,0) -- (2,4) node[right] {$P$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{minipage}}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.4\baselineskip` is a fudge factor to compensate for the spacing between the paragraph and the tikzpicture.

[image: scale adjustment]

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newlength{\tempdima}
\newlength{\tempdimb}

 \begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) -- (2,4) node[right] {$P$};
 \end{tikzpicture}}% get size of tikzpicture
\tempdimb=\ht\tempbox
\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{minipage}[c]{.38\textwidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla \par
\end{minipage}}% get size of second paragraph
\tempdima=\dimexpr \ht\tempbox + \dp\tempbox + .4\baselineskip
\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{minipage}[c]{.50\textwidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
\end{minipage}}% compute scale factor
\tempdima=\dimexpr \ht\tempbox + \dp\tempbox - \tempdima
\pgfmathparse{\tempdima/\tempdimb}%
\let\scale=\pgfmathresult

\fbox{\usebox{\tempbox}}\hfill%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c]{.38\textwidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 

\centering  \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=\scale]
 \draw (0,0) -- (2,4) node[right] {$P$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{minipage}}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, but isn't it possible to scale the whole picture so that it also deals with more complex pictures?

Comment: You can't specify the height, but you can specify the yscale.  Or you could use \resizebox.

Comment: Bit _try it_, I meant your code. That's a pity the borders don't perfectly match though (_cf._ arbitrary `0.4\baseline`).

Comment: Part of the problem is that yscale does not affect the size of $P$.